# What is the difference between a shared Saved Query and a View in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the difference between a shared Saved Query and a View in BigQuery?

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries) says that "one advantage of [a saved query] is that you can share a query that is incomplete." Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saved queries:

- Can contain arbitrary query text, and aren't necessarily valid.
- Can use DDL/DML (e.g. `DELETE FROM dataset.table WHERE x = 5;`

Logical views:

- Must be defined as a query (e.g. `SELECT x, y FROM dataset.table;`)
- Must be valid.